# Duplicate rows in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying my best to avoid using cursors- the amount of data is really huge. There is a table that looks like:

```
|Data| Multiplier|
-----------------|
|A   | 2         |
|B   | 3         |
|C   | 0         |
```

I need to get data from it in the following way:

```
|Data| Multiplier|
-----------------|
|A   | 2         |
|A   | 2         |
|B   | 3         |
|B   | 3         |
|B   | 3         |
```

So that the row appears as much times, as it's "Multiplier" value.
I know it's possible to use CONNECT statements in Oracle Database, but I need to do it in MSSQL.

Comment: Lookup Tally Tables, it becomes trivial then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just use a recursive CTE, if the numbers are not very big:

```
with cte as (
      select data, 1 as n, multiplier
      from t
      where multiplier > 0
      union all
      select data 1 + n, multiplier
      from cte
      where n < multiplier
    )
select data, multiplier
from cte;
```

There are other methods, using numbers as well:

```
select t.data, t.multiplier
from t join
     (select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as n
      from master..spt_values v
     ) n
     on n.n <= t.multiplier;
```

Comment: I ended up using numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need *recursive* way :

```
with t as (
     select data, Multiplier, 1 as seq
     from table
     where Multiplier > 0
     union all
     select data, Multiplier, seq+1
     from t
     where seq < Multiplier
)
select *
from t
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: It kind of doesn't work. -> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: @HirasawaYui. . . I just added `max recursive` hint to the query.

Answer (score 1):

You have to hard code the values but pretty clean

```
declare @t table (data char, multi int);
insert into @t values 
('A', 2),
('B', 3),
('C', 0);
select t.*
from @t t 
join (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) v(valueId) 
on v.valueId <= t.multi
```

Comment: I wish I could hard code them. The value of data may be anywhere in the range of int (from -2 147 483 648 to +2 147 483 647).

Comment: You could just create a table with those values once with a recursive cte.  Depending on you use scenario this might be the best solution.   It is hard from me to understand how you need a row repeated 2 billion times.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use cross apply

```
declare  @t table
(data1 varchar(50),mutli int)

insert into @t

values

('a',2),
('b',3),
('c',0),
('d',5)


select data1,mutli from @t a

cross apply (
select * from (
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select null)) as rn from master..spt_values
)x where a.mutli >= rn
)z
```